# Support JavaScript ES6 modules in code snippets

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

### Update December 2020

This month [Three.js](https://threejs.org) is scheduled to go ES6 module support only. No more support for `<script>` tags for all the loaders/controls/postprocessing etc.

[Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) is fairly popular with new programmers. It's also common for nothing to appear on the screen in case of failure with no errors.

Both of these mean that for new users to get support it's essential they be able to add a working [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Without one, almost without fail their question is off topic as being new they rarely know which code to post. Many of the existing examples and all the sample code going forward will be ES6 module / import based.

I'm sure other JavaScript libraries are gradually doing the same.

[JavaScript is the single most popular tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags).

So, here's a plead to please bump the priority to support ES6 modules in snippets because the people who need the help the most are the least likely to know how to work around the fact that modern JavaScript doesn't work in Stack Overflow snippets.

---

JavaScript and all modern browsers have added support for JavaScript modules and the `import` keyword and lots of developers are using it.

To use it you need to put `type="module"` in the script tag as in

```
<script type="module">

  // JavaScript code goes here

</script>
```

This enables using the `import` keyword. Example:

```
import * as THREE from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/108/three.module.js';
```

The current snippet editor provides no way to specify you want it to insert `type="module"` which means the only solution is to put a `<script>` tag in the HTML area

Example:

```html
<!-- I want to put this code in the JavaScript area, but I can't -->
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/108/three.module.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 2, 0.1, 5);
  camera.position.set(1.2,1,1);
  camera.lookAt(0,0,0);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
  const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x44aa88});
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(cube);

  const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, 1);
  light.position.set(1, 2, 4);
  scene.add(light);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

main();
</script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Unfortunately a large portion of the users asking questions don't have the experience to know why their snippet doesn't work. They'll post something like this

```js
import * as THREE from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/108/three.module.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 2, 0.1, 5);
  camera.position.set(1.2,1,1);
  camera.lookAt(0,0,0);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
  const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x44aa88});
  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(cube);

  const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, 1);
  light.position.set(1, 2, 4);
  scene.add(light);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

main();
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Which doesn't run and provides no visible error as to why. Yes there is an error in the JavaScript console but many new users have no clue to look there and looking would not help them fix the snippet.

Further, there is no syntax highlighting for JavaScript in the HTML area.

Can the snippet editor be updated to have an option to insert `type="module"` in the script tag that it puts the JavaScript portion of the snippet?

Note that as a far as implementation, both CodePen and JSFiddle handle it automatically. No idea what they check for. Maybe if there's an `import` statement [it adds `type="module"`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D81N6.jpg), if not [not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gIGf.jpg). Automatically handling it would be arguably be friendlier than some option a user will likely not notice.

Comment: Another benefit is that the snippet editor has syntax highlighting for the Javascript section, but not for inline `<script>` tags. (though once the snippet editing is complete, it's OK)

Comment: Could just be a checkbox below "Use Babel / ES2015".

Comment: *"Note that as a far as implementation, it might be ok just to set type="module" always for new snippets..."* Can't do that, it would break any snippet demonstrating things that happen at global scope (since modules are in their own scope).

Comment: Good point about always setting it being problematic. Still codepen jsfiddle are doing it automatically by checking for import

Comment: @gman I tried to follow your example to use something like https://github.com/mikeerickson/validatorjs in a stack snipped to no avail. It might be even worse to post a how-to.

Comment: There is still no module support and we have removed large portions of the non-module code base in `three.js`. The remaining UMD builds are going to be removed soon as well. Since there is still no ES6 module supports in code snippets, we can't provide embedded live examples with latest `three.js` releases anymore. As a workaround, I personally stick to a certain release (`r147`) or just share static code and add a link to jsfiddle/codesandbox. Both approaches are not ideal.

Comment: @Mugen87, it's not ideal but you can workaround it by putting a `<script type="module">` tag in the HTML section of the snippet. It's especially not ideal because a person asking is unlikely to know the workaround. It's pretty strange though that it's 2023 and S.O. hasn't fixed this. Maybe they're concerned it would break old snippets but they could probably make it conditional on the creation date or last modification date so not really sure why they haven't done it.

Comment: @Mugen87, ps: I'd suggest you and MrDoob tweet this issue and try to get this upvoted. That's likely the only way S.O. will notice

Answer (score 7):

An ugly but working way to use modules may be:

```js
document.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => 
  document.readyState === "complete" && theActualSnippetCode());

function theActualSnippetCode() {
  log("hithere!", {thisIs: "pretty ugly", but: "it works"});
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
  import {Logger} from 
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/KooiInc/DOM-Utilities@v1.1.3/Log.min.js";
  window.log = Logger();
</script>
```