# How do I make a code snippet with the new editor? Where did the button go?

Tags: support, stack-snippets, stacks-editor

Here is a comparison of old:

[image: Original editor toolbar, with Stack Snippet button visible]

and new:

[image: New Stacks Editor toolbar, with no Stack Snippet button]

Where did the code snippet go? How can I make it now?

Comment: That feature doesn’t exist yet

Comment: According to this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381279/397219) on [meta.se] the snippet feature was added back in August 2022, however, [another post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387592/397219) on the site from March this year is in [[meta-tag:status-review]] as it's missing (again). Honestly, I don't know why Stack Overflow are so adamant to push an incomplete product on their users. It's like forcing employees to drive the company's new car, but the problem with it is that they haven't added brakes to it yet, so you have to use your feet to slow down.

Comment: FYI. you can still add a code snippet by **editing your question after you post it**. That is the workaround I have used for now but hopefully, it gets fixed soon.

Answer (score 11):

I can't find anywhere where it's called out explicitly, but the new editor just doesn't have built-in Snippet support yet.

*TL;DR*: The new Stacks Editor was given plugin support, which was designed with functionality like Snippets in mind-- but no Snippets plugin has been actually announced or developed yet, as far as I can tell. A more detailed history of the editor with citations follows below.

---

It was mentioned in [the initial Alpha release for the new Stack Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033) that Snippet support was being temporarily dropped while the editor was getting worked on initially:

> Removed:
> ...
>
> - **Stack Snippets** (temporary) - We couldn't get Snippets built into the initial alpha test, so if you need to add a snippet to a post, you'll need to disable the alpha to do so.

But we're well beyond that Alpha release at this point. As described in [a follow-up update announcing the Beta release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380295), [Beta 1](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/releases/tag/v0.6.0) (released in early July of '22) added official external plugin support, which was called out as required for adding code snippet functionality back in:

> **Beta 1**: This was released on July 5, 2022 and is in production as of July 12. [Full release notes are available](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/releases/tag/v0.6.0). The main accomplishment of this release is to ensure the back-end library is feature-complete as compared to the old editor — meaning the Stacks team laid the groundwork that’ll allow the dev teams responsible for the Public Q&A sites to work on Stack Exchange-specific functionality. With this, the latter teams will be able in the future to build plugins into the editor, with the goal of reaching feature-parity (for all sites) to the old editor available on the network. Some of the issues addressed on this release were:
> ...
>
> - and [adding official external plugin support](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/111), which will be required for supporting various extra editor features across the Stack Exchange network, **such as** ... **code snippets** ...

[Beta 2](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/releases/tag/v0.7.0) was released later that same month, with no further mention of snippets getting added back. We also [haven't heard anything further on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stacks-editor+product-discovery) regarding the Stacks Editor since then.

We can see that editor development has continued in the meantime via [fairly regular releases on GitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/releases). We're up to v0.8.7 (Beta 1 was v0.6, Beta 2 was v0.7), but no public progress updates on Snippet support specifically have been given in the meantime that I've been able to find (though it's always possible for something to be buried in a comment or GitHub issue somewhere).

I'm speculating now, but assuming the external plugin support is indeed feature-complete as described, it sounds like the holdup might be with the Snippet-plugin itself, rather than with the editor. Snippets have [needed a good overhaul](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389108) [for a *long* time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375887), so it's not that surprising to me that they haven't ported the feature over yet; it's probably a good a time as any to finally take on a full rewrite and make them more useful and less prone to [needing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377153) [manual updates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424776).

<sub>Or at least, one can *hope* that's what they're doing.</sub>

Comment: What in the ACTUAL Frick is this? I have a standard answer to everybody that do not post code that they should use the `[<>]` SNIPPET EDITOR and now it is just wrapping in `\`\`\``  ???? https://imgur.com/a/VaRxZ0Y - I did miss Es6 support, but could live with that. Give us back the editor!

Comment: @mplungjan i understand your pain in every way. the `[<>]` now has nothing to do with code snippet but rather just adds a blockcode now.

Comment: @danik0011 except after it was edited

Comment: @mplungjan i know that there is still the old ui when editing and answering

Answer (score 4):

The code snippet is currently not available when you first ask the question **but you can add a code snippet immediately after you post the question by editing it**.

You can still of course add snippets in any answer. You can temporarily prepare the snippet somewhere else so that you can add it to your question by editing it right after you post it.

This workaround is obviously not ideal and hopefully, this feature will get fixed soon.